# Why doesn't `return if ` work in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

It's fairly natural to use `return` followed by a simple expression. This works to an extent with PowerShell:

```
    return 1+1;                     # evaluates the expression and returns 2

    function Increment-Variable([int] $a) 
    { 
        return $a + 1 
    }

    return Increment-Variable 23;   #Expression evaluated: returns 24
```

But for some reason, my PowerShell (v4) rejects the following.

```
    return if ($True) { 2 } else { 3 } #Error: Expression not parsed/evaluated
```

with

```
    The term 'if' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
    script file, or operable program.
```

Enclosing in brackets doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose the statement in a sub-expression, and the parser won't complain:

```
return $(if ($True) { 2 } else { 3 })
```

---

This is documented in the `about_Operators` help page:

```
Get-Help about_Operators
```

You can find out about operator and bracket precendence in the `about_Operator_Precedence` page:

```
Get-Help about_Operator_Precedence
```